# Increasing the maximum length of cross-site publishing content

Tags: 2013, cross-site-publishing

I have set up an authoring site collection and a publishing site collection for cross-site publishing where the pages library of the authoring site collection gets cross-site published to the target site collection. The actual content gets written to the source page's `Page Content` property.
Tests have shown that the maximum length of content that gets fully published is 2^14 = 16384 characters. Although I can assign more content to the `Page Content` property, when consuming it after publishing the data gets truncated after 2^14 chars.

Where exactly is this limit introduced (publishing catalog? result source?) and how can I increase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this data coming through a managed property field? About [half-way down this list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx) it shows a limit of 16KB for "retrievable managed property size."

It says you can use PowerShell to set the P.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreForRetrieval, but that is all I know.